# How do I animate CSS box-shadow depth (with jQuery or CSS3 transitions)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

This does do the delays but doesn't seem to apply the style changes until the end:

```
for (i=20;i>=0;i--) {            
    var boxShadow = i+"px "+i+"px "+i+"px #888";
    $('article').css("box-shadow", boxShadow);
    sleep(20);
}
function sleep(ms)
{
    var dt = new Date();
    dt.setTime(dt.getTime() + ms);
    while (new Date().getTime() < dt.getTime());
}
```

This doesn't apply the delays at all:

```
for (i=20;i>=0;i--) {            
    var boxShadow = i+"px "+i+"px "+i+"px #888";
    $('article').delay(500).css("box-shadow", boxShadow);
}
```

Can this be done more easily with css3 transitions?  Am I just making some small jquery error in the delay sample?

Thank you to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use classes and `setTimeout` to utilize CSS3 transitions for your animation effect:

CSS --

```
#some-element {
    -webkit-transition : all 0.5s linear;
       -moz-transition : all 0.5s linear;
        -ms-transition : all 0.5s linear;
         -o-transition : all 0.5s linear;
            transition : all 0.5s linear;
}
#some-element.ani-state {
    -webkit-box-shadow : 0 0 24px #000;
       -moz-box-shadow : 0 0 24px #000;
            box-shadow : 0 0 24px #000;
}
```

I used `all` for the transition declarations because of Chrome... some versions of Chrome use `-webkit-box-shadow` and newer versions use `box-shadow`. `all` isn't a big deal if you aren't changing any other properties of the element (or if you want to animate those property changes).

JS --

```
$(function () {

    var $someElement = $('#some-element');

    $someElement.on('click', function () {
        $someElement.addClass('ani-state');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $someElement.removeClass('ani-state');
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/tvfPq/1/

Note that in the demo I used two `box-shadows`: `box-shadow : 0 0 24px #000, inset 0 0 24px #999;`

Comment: Delays are already a part of css transitions:

`transition: property duration timing-function delay;` so if you wanted your transition to have a 500ms delay, you just include that. `transition: all 0.5s linear 500ms;`

Comment: @scurker Notice inside the `setTimeout` is `.removeClass()`, so I'm returning the element to it's original state. The animation starts without delay. The `setTimeout`'s timeout is set to the duration of the CSS transition so it completes fully and then reverts to the original state.

Comment: I misread the original question. It seems like the best way to do this would be to use @keyframes instead if you wanted to restore the animation to it's original state after it has run its course.

Comment: @scurker Honestly it's just a demo, the OP should be able to extract out what he/she needs to run CSS animations via JS as he/she wants. I like the idea of keyframes, but I dislike re-coding all the different vender prefixes...

Comment: And actually, it would be better to bind to `transitionend` instead of using setTimeout. [Mozilla developer docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions#Detecting_the_completion_of_a_transition) has more on this. Not to mention `setTimeout()` has its own issues.

Comment: The actual effect I wanted was for an element to come away from the page by it's shadow increasing.  This was more than enough of an example.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey scurker... care to show an example of what you're talking about with use of transitionend?

Comment: @danieltalsky You just bind to transitionend events instead of using setTimeout. See this updated code: [jsfiddle.net/hVyUq/](http://jsfiddle.net/hVyUq/).

Answer (score 2):

A jquery plugin was recently released that does this. Take a peak: [Shadowmation](http://plugins.jquery.com/Shadowmation/)